# How to store only the nth substring into a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a="how are you?";
```

In the above example I want to store the second word "are" into another variable in a single step.
I don't want to use something like below

```
var bigArray = a.split(" ");
var secondText = bigArray[1];
```

as we may need to store the entire paragraph into a big array and consume a lot of memory without any use.

I would like to know if there is some function which works as below

```
var secondText=specialFunction(a," ",1);
```

so that we will get the second substring when the paragraph is split by " "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would spend my time worrying about more important things than the size of some arrays.

Anyway, you could try using a regexp:

```
var secondText = (a.match(/ (\w+)/) || []) [1];
```

This reads as "find a space, then capture the following word".

The `|| []` part is meant to deal with the situation where there is no match (for example, no second word). In that case, the result will be `[][1]` which is `undefined`.

This finds only the second word. What about the more general case? Since we are not allowed to split the string on spaces, because that would create an array and the OP doesn't want that due to memory concerns. So, we will instead build a dynamic regexp. To find the *n*th word, we want to skip over the first *n-1* spaces. Or, to be more precise, we want to skip over the first word, some spaces, then the second word, then some more spaces, etc. So the regexp is

```
/(?:\w+ ){n}(\w+)/
  ^^                  NO CAPTURING GROUP
    ^^^^              WORD FOLLOWED BY SPACE
         ^^^          N TIMES
            ^^^^^     CAPTURE FOLLOWING WORD
```

The `?:` is to avoid this being treated as a capturing group. We build the regexp using

```
function make_nth_word_regexp(n) {
    n--;
    return new RegExp("(?:\\w+ ){" + n + "}(\\w+)");
}
```

Now look for your nth word:

```
var fifth_word = str.match(make_nth_word_regexp(5)) [1];

> "Hey there you".match(make_nth_word_regexp(3))[1]
< "you"
```

Comment: The code exactly finds the second word, But I meant a more general case where I can find the nth word so that when I write `var secondText = (a.match(/ (\w+)/) || []) [0];` I get 'how' and when I write `var secondText = (a.match(/ (\w+)/) || []) [2];` I get 'you?'. But when I use the above code I get 'are' and a blank space respectively.

Comment: @Sandeep You're contradiction yourself. You say you want a "thing" form which you an retrieve the nth word using the syntax `thing[n]`, the the only such thing would be an array, which you said you don't want to create due to supposed memory concerns. Anyway, I will update my answer with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to regex is just to use substring(). Something like

```
var a="how are you";
alert(a.substring(a.indexOf(" "), a.length).substring(0, a.indexOf(" ")+1));
```